# Доступ к оболочке события

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Ситуация:**

Я перехватываю событие и устанавливаю в кастомное свойство свои данные

```
jQuery("#element_id").click(function(){
   event.custom_property = {'any_data'};
});
```

Позже данное событие перехватывает и обрабатывает функция подключенного стороннего компонента.
Происходит там примерно следующее:

```
if(e.hasOwnProperty('custom_property')){
    //обработка прокинутых данных
}
```

Однако, к моему огорчению мои данные не были обработаны.

Отладив в debugger'е, я установил что `e.hasOwnProperty('custom_property')` возвращает `false` и не переходит к обработке данных.

Проинспектировав сам объект события, обнаружил что это не оригинальный объект события, а оболочка созданная jQuery(насколько я могу судить), со всем тем же набором данных, кучей плюшек от jQuery, но при этом без пользовательских свойств.

Оригинальный объект события также доступен в оболочке. Он находится в свойстве originalEvent. И уже в нём есть все те данные, которые я прокинул.
[image: Событие]

Соответственно, проверка `e.originalEvent.hasOwnProperty('custom_property')` уже будет давать необходимый нам результат, однако по понятным причинам я не могу просто так пойти и запилить правку в стороннем компоненте ибо после первого же обновления, всё это великолепие слетит.

По-хорошему нужно прокинуть данные именно в оболочку.
Однако, проблема в том, что при обработке события я получаю именно оригинальный объект события.

**Внимание, вопрос:**

Есть ли способ, при обработке события с помощью jQuery получить не оригинальные объект события, а его оболочку, созданную всё тем же jQuery.

Comment: `.click(function(e){ e.custom_property = {'any_data'};})`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо тебе, добрый человек) Оформите, ответ  - я вам плюсик хоть поставлю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым параметром всех обработчиков является объект события. Не зависимо от того нативный обработчик (добавленный с помощью [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)), либо обработчик jQuery.

В обоих случаях это будет нужный объект события: нативный в первом случае и обертка jQuery во втором.

Следовательно нужно изменить код так:

```
jQuery("#element_id").click(function(e){
   e.custom_property = {'any_data'};
});
```

Кроме того нужно убедиться, что этот обработчик будет выполняться *до* перехватывательщика, иначе данное поле все равно будет не определено в момент проверки.